# Error when I upgrade my Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and download new packages

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

When I upgrade my Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and download new packages, I saw the following error message:

```
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-noto-cjk/fonts-noto-cjk_1.004+repack2-1~ubuntu1_all.deb Size mismatch
```

Comment: Can you download the package manually using `wget -c http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-noto-cjk/fonts-noto-cjk_1.004+repack2-1~ubuntu1_all.deb`

Answer (score 0):

If you are still using Ubuntu 14.04 and want to update it to Ubuntu 16.04, this mismatch could be due to the location you are downloading updates from. To solve the problem try this :

1. Open Software & Update.
2. Change the Server location in "Download from : "
3. Try again